# Varios metodos Threads en JAVA

Tags: java, hilos

Sabemos que una clase que extiende de `Thread` tiene un método `run()` el cual es 1 hilo independiente, pero como puedo tener varios hilos en 1 sola clase ?

Por ejemplo, si tengo una clase `Jugador` y tiene 2 métodos (correr, disparar), ¿cómo puedo hacer que esos 2 métodos sean hilos independientes en 1 misma clase.
O tendría que crear 2 clases, una para correr y otra para disparar, porque solo se puede tener un método `run()`.

**Main**

```
package hilos;

public class Hilos {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    acciones accion1 = new acciones();
    accion1.start();

}

}
```

**Clase con Hilos**

```
package hilos;

public class acciones extends Thread {

@Override
public void run()
{

// Código para correr 

} 

// Código para correr para nadar ????????????? como seria ??

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que debemos aclarar es que el método `run` de la clase `Thread` no es un hilo en si mismo. La clase `Thread` nos permite crear hilos independientes por nuestra cuenta para ejecutar un determinado código que es el que incluímos dentro de su método `run`. ¿Cómo funciona esto (a grandes rasgos y sin ponernos demasiado técnicos? Pués cuando creamos un objeto de tipo `Thread` y ejecutamos su método `start` le estamos indicando a la máquina virtual de Java que cree un nuevo hilo y que ejecute dentro de este el código del método `run`.

Teniendo lo anterior claro, y para logar lo que pides, se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
public class Acciones {

    public void correr() {...}

    public void disparar() {...}
}    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Acciones acciones = new Acciones();

    new Thread(() -> acciones.correr()).start();
    new Thread(() -> acciones.disparar()).start();

}
```

Aquí lo que hicimos fue crear un objeto de tipo `Acciones` y ejecutar cada uno de sus métodos en un `Thread` independiente.

***Nota***: Por si no estás familiarizado con la programación funcional en Java, este código:

```
() -> acciones.correr()
```

es equivalente a

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        acciones.correr();
    }
}
```

**IMPORTANTE:** Si los métodos de una clase se ejecutan en diferentes hilos y estos métodos hacen uso de recursos compartidos de la propia clase, debes utilizar técnicas de exclusión mutua como por ejemplo la sincronización. Esto también aplica a aquellos métodos que compartan cualquier tipo de recursos, ya sea que estos métodos estén en una misma clase o no. La multiprogramación o programación concurrente no es una tema trivial y te recomiendo que la estudies en profundidad antes de aplicarla en proyectos reales.

Comment: Es inevitable utilizar programación funcional para realizarlo ?

Comment: Por supuesto que no, por eso incluí el mismo código sin utilizar expresiones lambdas. Solo que las expresiones lambdas son mucho menos verbosas.